# Conditional: I would be planning

Tags: conditional-constructions

Brief question:

> If I were a teacher, I **would be planning** a trip there twice a year.

Is it ok to use a gerund in the main clause? Is the usage correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a verb ends in the letters **ing** does not necessarily mean that it is a gerund. And in your example, it is not a gerund. It is a tense of the verb (sometimes) described as the **conditional progressive**.

Progressive tenses are formed with the verb **to be** and by adding **ing** to the infinitive. Examples of these tenses are given at the site referenced below.

**Planning** would be a gerund if it were used as a noun, as in:

> Planning is the hardest part of the job.

But when you use it after auxilliaries/modals as in **was planning, will be planning** you are using it as a verb, not a gerund, and it's perfectly correct.

https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/gerund_progressive.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder some issue yet. In inversion of the first conditional have I met two cases. 1. Should + Present Simple, Present Simple, 2. Should + Present Simple, Future Simple. Are both correct and/or have the same meaning?

Comment: @DopowiedzSe Make your query a separate question, giving examples of the use of the tenses - and your own opinion about their meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the cited use is just a continuous verb form, not a "noun-like" gerund. It's a *very* fine point, but to my mind one difference between...

> 1: *If I were X, I would do Y*
>    ...and...
>    2: *If I were X, I would be doing Y*

(apart from the obvious fact that the syntactically simpler version #1 is far more common) is that the *continuous* version #2 carries slightly stronger allusions to the *present, real-world* situation. That's to say, *on average* a speaker who chooses to say *If I were married, I would **be having** sex every day* is likely to be a bit more "sexually frustrated" than others who say *If I were married, I would **have** sex every day*. The first speaker's choice of tense implies he finds it easier to imagine himself in the hypothetical context being referenced, because *it's something he thinks about anyway.*

I know that's a flippant example, but I think the principle holds good, and can be applied to many other contexts. The bottom line is *continuous forms often imply greater "immediacy".* Thus, given these two possibilities...

> 3: *If I were you, I'd eat less junk food*
>    4: *If I were you, I'd be eating less junk food*

...I'd be inclined to see #3 as just a standard turn of phrase conveying the basic message *You should eat less junk food*, where #4 more strongly implies that the speaker really is *imagining himself in the addressee's circumstances* (so perhaps one might say his advice is more "heartfelt").